# how to make my login page switch to <LoggedInTemplate> after verifying User from my own database in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, ado.net, master-pages

I have created my own login page and linked it with Master page. Also I created my own database named "Learning". Now when user click the login button, it performs the database query successfully but after verifying user, the control doesn't move in to . My code is shown as below:
My login.aspx page is

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="MasterAjaxNavigation.NewAccount.Login" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>Login Information  </h2> 
    <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server" >
        <AnonymousTemplate>
            <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" OnAuthenticate="Login1_Authenticate" BackColor="#FFFBD6" BorderColor="#FFDFAD" BorderPadding="4" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#333333" TextLayout="TextOnTop" VisibleWhenLoggedIn="False" >
                <InstructionTextStyle Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Black" />
                <LayoutTemplate>
                   <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName" CssClass="text-danger">Email: </asp:Label><br />
                   <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="box" EnableViewState="false" MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox> <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="The email field is required." >*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
                   <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password" CssClass="text-danger">Password: </asp:Label><br />
                   <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" CssClass="box" EnableViewState="false" MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox> <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="The password field is required." >*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
                   <asp:Button ID="log_in" runat="server" Text="Login" CommandName="Login" CssClass="btn btn-default" OnClick="log_in_Click"/>
                   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                 </LayoutTemplate>
                <LoginButtonStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#990000" />
                <TextBoxStyle Font-Size="0.8em" />
                <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="0.9em" ForeColor="White" />
            </asp:Login>
        </AnonymousTemplate>
        <LoggedInTemplate>
            <p>Hello I am Logged in !!!</p>

            </LoggedInTemplate>

    </asp:LoginView>

    <br />

   </asp:Content>
```

And my login.aspx.cs file is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace MasterAjaxNavigation.NewAccount
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        Int32 verify;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void log_in_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Learning;Integrated Security=True;";

                Control login = LoginView1.FindControl("Login1");
                //Int32 verify;
                string query1 = "Select count(*) from Login where username='" + ((TextBox)login.FindControl("UserName")).Text + "' and Password='" + ((TextBox)login.FindControl("Password")).Text + "' ";
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
                con.Open();
                verify = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
                con.Close();
                if (verify > 0)
                {
                    //Response.Redirect("succesful.aspx
                    ((Label)login.FindControl("Label1")).Text = "Successful";

                }
                else
                {
                    //Response.Redirect("unsuccesful.aspx", true);
                    ((Label)login.FindControl("Label1")).Text = "Failed";
                }
            }
            catch (System.NullReferenceException s)
            {

            }
        }

        protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs e)
        {
            if (verify > 0)
            {
                e.Authenticated = true;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Authenticated = false;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Even the compiler is moved to e.Authenticated = true it doesnt go to the < LoggedInTemplate >. Any one please help?

Comment: You seem to be simulating a login without actually logging the user in. What authentication mechanism are you using? If you are using forms authentication you need to create a Forms authentication ticket or implement a cusom membership provider. Simply validating against a database and/or setting ` e.Authenticated = true` in the Authenticate event does not log the user in.

Comment: Thanks. I thought this authentication stuff has something to do with MVC or entity framework. Anyways which authentication mechanism is best? Can you please suggest me any easy step by step guide for creating an authentication mechanism?